# Jenkins Windows Node returning CreateProcess error=193

Tags: java, windows, jenkins, ant, codeception

I'm attempting to set up a Windows node for Jenkins (master is running on Mac/ElCapitan) to run Codeception acceptance tests.

The jenkins jnlp file seems to be running appropriately, Jenkins has created its directories on the Windows node.  I'm asking it to run a test via an ant build in Firefox only.  This is a successful test running on the master/Apple machine.

I can type "codecept" into the command prompt on the Windows Node in any directory and get the default help message.

I can run the test by going into the Jenkins created folders on the Windows Node machine via the command prompt with codecept run tests/acceptance/all/test.

When trying to do this through Jenkins from the master machine I get the following error:

```
C:\jenkins\workspace\nodeTest\browser\firefox\label\Windows10\build.xml:147: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\jenkins\workspace\nodeTest\browser\firefox\label\Windows10\vendor\bin\codecept" (in directory "C:\jenkins\workspace\nodeTest\browser\firefox\label\Windows10"): CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

The ant file:

```
<property environment="env"/>

<property name="codecept" value="${basedir}/vendor/bin/codecept"/>

<target name="InvalidLogin" depends="CleanPics, InvalidLoginRun" />

<target name="CleanPics" description="clean out directories from previous run.">
    <delete dir="${basedir}/tests/_output" />
    <mkdir dir="${basedir}/tests/_output" />
    <mkdir dir="${basedir}/tests/_output/debug" />
```

```
<target name="InvalidLoginRun" description="confirm invalid credentials don't allow login">
    <exec executable="${codecept}" failonerror="true">
        <arg value="run" />
        <arg value="--debug" />
        <arg value="tests/acceptance/all/00loginsInvalidCest.php" />
        <arg value="--xml" />
        <arg value="--env" />
        <arg value="${browser}" />
    </exec>
```

Googling has led me to answers that I should be using a ShellExecute instead of a CreateProcess command but I can't figure out how to configure the Ant file to do this.  Any ideas?

Comment: Use vendor/bin/codecept.bat on Windows

Comment: That worked!  Please enter it as an answer though so other Windows novices can more easily find this answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`vendor/bin/codecept` file is for Linux and other kinds of unix-like operating systems.
Use `vendor/bin/codecept.bat` on Windows.